# Por que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática?

Tags: javascript, variáveis-globais

Estou lendo um livro de JavaScript chamado *"JavaScript The Good Parts"* e nele em vários momentos o autor fala que não se deve utilizar variáveis globais porque elas são do "mal". Por que elas são consideradas do "mal"? Que tipo de problemas elas podem causar?

Comment: Só uma curiosidade: _são do mal_ é alguma expressão utilizada no Brasil com uma conotação negativa?

Comment: @Zuul Sim, seria como "globals are evil"

Comment: Há informações complementares sobre o assunto na tag [tag:variáveis-globais]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Difícil entendimento

Uma variável faz maior sentido quando declarada e utilizada junto ao código que a manipula. Muitas vezes em um contexto global fica difícil entender (por completo) o papel daquela variável.

## Acoplamento

Quando diferentes partes do seu código acessam essa mesma variável global você acaba acoplando grande parte do seu código, ficando difícil sua modularização (reutilizar apenas aquele "pedaço" do seu código).

## Regras de acesso e concorrência

Com todo mundo acessando a variável fica díficil forçar restrições a ela e, principalmente, coordenar o acesso de múltiplas threads.

## Conflitos de namespace

O nome das variáveis globais afetarão todo seu namespace. Isso acaba poluindo o código pois muitas vezes você será obrigado a utilizar outro nome ou especificar o nome por completo (com o namespace), o que normalmente você não faria.

## Com a palavra, *Crockford*

Segue um trecho do próprio [livro](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/JavaScript.html?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C) que você citou:

> Because a global variable can be changed by any part of the program at any time, they can significantly complicate the behavior of the program. Use of global variables degrades the reliability of the programs that use them.
>
> Global variables make it harder to run independent subprograms in the same program. If the subprograms happen to have global variables that share the same names, then they will interfere with each other and likely fail, usually in difficult to diagnose ways.
>
> Lots of languages have global variables. For example, Java's public static members are global variables. The problem with JavaScript isn't just that it allows them, it requires them. JavaScript does not have a linker. All compilation units are loaded into a common global object.

Comment: Acho que seu quarto ponto deveria ser o primeiro – pelo menos a citação do Crockford é toda sobre ele, e a pergunta parte da posição desse autor.

Comment: @bfavaretto, os pontos que citei não estão em nenhuma ordem específica. E só adicionei a citação do *Crockford* para *ilustrar* a resposta, os pontos são meus mesmo ;)

Answer (score 20):

O principal problema são as colisões de nome. Se você escreve um código que depende de uma variável global `qualquer`, e mais adiante inclui um script feito por outra pessoa que também usa uma global de mesmo nome, um código vai interferir no outro. Vão aparecer bugs, e até você entender o motivo, muito tempo será perdido.

Exemplo:

**Script A**

```
var contador = 0;
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(contador++);
}, 1000);
```

**Script B**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    contador = 0;
}, 5000);
```

A cada 5 segundos o script B vai resetar o **seu** contador para zero – porque ele não é *só seu*...

Por isso a recomendação é evitar ao máximo o número de variáveis globais em seu código, reduzindo-o a zero se possível, ou criando uma única global com um objeto representando um *namespace* seu, e pendurando propriedades nesse objeto. Assim, aumentam as chances de seu código conviver em harmonia com o código dos outros.

Comment: "criando uma única global com um objeto representando um namespace seu, e pendurando propriedades nesse objeto" boa observação! Às vezes é inevitável usar globais, mas é sempre bom mantê-las ao mínimo.

Comment: @bfavaretto não há problema em se referir ao título da pergunta em comentário de resposta, chapeleiro :) De qualquer forma removi o comentário.

Comment: Gostei do "chapeleiro", @Diego! :)

Answer (score 2):

## Reflexo de um projeto (design) inadequado (uma possibilidade)

Conforme a resposta em [Alternativas para variáveis globais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153814/alternativas-para-vari%C3%A1veis-globais/404092#404092), a suspeita é que o *design* esteja acrescentando uma complexidade acidental. Noutras palavras, o domínio do problema em questão não exige um *design* para o qual a implementação naturalmente faz uso de variáveis globais. Em vez disso, o *design* acidentalmente acrescenta tal complexidade por opção do projetista.

Quando variáveis globais são empregadas, ou dados globais, em geral, vários módulos, rotinas ou classes, ou qualquer que seja o nome de trechos do código em questão, estão referenciando tais dados globais. Em consequência, a mudança na estrutura de tais dados, por exemplo, tende a gerar um efeito em cascata de mudanças. O código pertinente ao que tais dados globais representam não está localizado, mas disperso.

O parágrafo acima apresenta um motivo para evitar dados globais, especialmente, claro, se foram introduzidos em decorrência de uma complexidade acidental do *design*.