# Como melhorar o workflow do código sem utilizar ajax síncrono?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como melhorar este script?

A função `copiaArea()` deve pegar o primeiro retorno do array e enviar para a área de transferência do windows, detalhe: Estou desenvolvendo para IE, funciona exclusivamente nele esta função. Porém a var global `numero`, não recebe a tempo na 2ª chamada da `listaNumeros()`, após o `adicionarNúmero()`(gerado por trigger no BD, por motivos de tratamento de data e sequência de numeração direto no mysql.).

A questão é a seguinte, as contra-indicações de utilizar o `async:false` no ajax são pertinentes aqui?

Outro detalhe, é que isto só roda em servidor de rede local, não depende da internet.

```
/*
* Loader da numeração
* @author marcelo aymone
*/

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#loading').show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
});

var ip;
var numero;

function inserirLinha(array) {
    var linha = $("<tr>");
    var col = "";
    col += "<td>" + array.num + "</td>";
    col += "<td>" + array.time + "</td>";
    linha.append(col);
    if (array.ip == ip) {
        linha.toggleClass("info");
    }
    $("#numeros").append(linha);
}

function sysMsg(msg) {
    $("#alertas").empty().append(msg);
}

function copiaArea(txt) {
    if (window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData) {
        clipboardData.setData('text', txt);
    }
}

function atualizaTabela(data) {
    var msg = "";
    if (data.status) {
        msg = "<div class=\"alert alert-success text-center\">";
        msg += "<h4>Sucesso!</h4>";
        msg += "Seu número foi gerado com sucesso!";
        msg += "</div>";
    } else {
        msg = "<div class=\"alert alert-error\">";
        msg += "<h4>Sucesso!</h4>";
        msg += "Ocorreu um erro e não foi possível gerar um número.";
        msg += "</div>";
    }
    $("#numeros").empty();
    listarNumeros();
    sysMsg(msg);
}

/*
* ListarNumeros recebe o seguinte json:
* {"lista":[{"num":"2014\/1618","ip":"10.120.2.35","time":"15\/05\/2014"}],"cliente":"10.120.2.35"}
**Possui \/ por causa do json_encode(), mas funciona ok.
*/

function listarNumeros() {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false, async:false});
    $.getJSON("/intracake/Numeros/listar.json")
            .done(function(data) {
                ip = data.cliente;
                numero = data.lista[0].num; //Pega o 1 resultado do array, último num gerado.
                $.each(data.lista, function(index, array) {
                    inserirLinha(array);
                });
            });
}
/*
* Recebe como retorno do json: {"status":true}
*/
function adicionarNumero() {
    $.post("/intracake/Numeros/adicionar.json")
            .done(function(data) {
                atualizaTabela(data);
                copiaArea(numero);
            });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    listarNumeros();
});
```

Script Html+php (cakephp):

```
<?php
 echo $this->Html->script('numeros-run', array('inline' => false));
?>
<style>
    .centralizado {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        float: none !important;
    }
    .table td, .table th {
        text-align: center;   
    }
</style>

<div class="span10">
    <div id="alertas"></div>
    <p class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button" onclick="adicionarNumero();">Gerar número!</button></p>
    <div id="loading" class="text-center"><p><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif"></p></div>
    <p class="text-center lead">Últimos números gerados:</p>
    <div class="span4 centralizado">
        <table id="numeros" class="table table-bordered">
        </table>
    </div>
    <p class="text-center">
        <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
        Todos números gerados pelo seu ip, 
        aparecem destacados em azul.
    </p>
    <p class="text-center">
        <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
        Ao gerar um número, ele é enviado para a área de transferência do windows.<br>
        <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
        Compatível apenas com Microsoft Internet Explorer.<br>
        <strong class="text-error">Você precisa aceitar na janela que abrirá</strong>, para que o número possa ser copiado automaticamente.<br>
        Depois basta você colar("ctrl+v") em qualquer lugar.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sim, pode travar tudo. O que você precisa é de um esquema de sincronismo (criado por você, e não pelo jQuery) utilizando uma variável global, por exemplo `var estado = 0;` Quando você chamar uma das duas funções, some 1 à variável, e chame uma terceira função `executaFim()`. Dentro de `executaFim()`, você valida se `estado` vale 2. Se sim, execute seu código que depende das **duas** outras funções terem executado. Caso contrário, não faça nada.

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn, isso não dá no mesmo? porque se colocar uma condição que permita não executar nada, é o mesmo resultado do ajax não possuir retorno e manter a página estática.

Comment: Não, não dá na mesma, não. Porque, apesar de "não fazer nada", pelo menos não travou a tela do usuário, enquanto a resposta não chega ;)

Comment: Entendi... Mas não quero fazer isto de modo que parece uma gambiarra, gostaria de ajustar no padrão de pilha de execução de callback's.

Comment: Se eu adicionar a callback `.fail({return false;})` como callback da própria requisição ajax, não irá "destravar" a página e continuar a execução?

Comment: Isso não é "gambiarra". Isso é uma espécie de [máquina de estados](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_estados_finitos) bem simples.

Comment: Onde é chamada a função `adicionarNumero`?

Comment: O "travamento" não é devido a erro ou sucesso, mas sim, devido à demora dos dados chegar à máquina do cliente (sejam dados corretos ou errados)

Comment: Entendi, vou dar uma lida no link... e tentar entender como implementar, obrigado @carlosrafaelgn

Comment: @bfavaretto:
No html, onclick de um botão.
`<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button" onclick="adicionarNumero();">Gerar número!</button>`

Comment: O link é só para esclarecer que não é gambiarra fazer isso que eu falei (usar a variável `estado`). Não precisa ler ele inteiro apenas para implementar essa sugestão, caso você tenha pressa ;)

Comment: Sim, entendi, não to com pressa não, to nessa pelo aprendizado!
Na verdade eu cuido da infra... mas sabe como é né... a gente sempre busca a grama do vizinho.

Comment: @bfavaretto adicionei o HTML, repara não no monte de código, é porque to usando cakephp, twitter bootstrap e as requisições em formato ajax com jquery.

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Eu só não entendi o seguinte, `if (estado ==1)` após a execução do script, mesmo assim continua sem funcionar, isso fica rodando num `for` para perceber que `estado` foi alterado?
Como estabelecer esse "listener" para verificar que `estado` foi alterado? Tentei achar algum exemplo pela net.. mas somente scripts bem complexos, fazendo parte de aplicações longas.

Comment: Pensei em utilizar algo parecido com isso: http://www.douglaspasqua.com/2013/08/14/javascript-e-funcoes-de-retorno-callback/

Comment: Tente ver se a resposta dada era o que você queria, ou dê uma olhada nesse fiddle que acabei de criar (as linhas marcadas com `@@@` foram as que criei): http://jsfiddle.net/USnmL/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, o fluxo do código postado, com o uso de ajax assíncrono, é o seguinte:

1. Botão clicado, `adicionarNumero` é chamado.
2. JSON (`adicionar.json`) recebido, `atualizaTabela` é chamado.
3. `atualizaTabela` chama `listarNumeros`.
4. `copiaArea` é chamado, passando o valor anterior de `numero` pois a resposta do `listar.json` ainda não chegou.
5. Chega a resposta do `listar.json` e a global `numero` é atualizada (tarde demais!)

#### Solução

Considerando que você não quer chamar `copiaArea` sempre que `listarNumeros` for executada, e sim somente após o `adicionarNumero`, sugiro tirar proveito das [*promises*](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) retornadas pelos métodos de ajax do jQuery, assim:

```
function atualizaTabela(data) {
    var msg = "";
    if (data.status) {
        msg = "<div class=\"alert alert-success text-center\">";
        msg += "<h4>Sucesso!</h4>";
        msg += "Seu número foi gerado com sucesso!";
        msg += "</div>";
    } else {
        msg = "<div class=\"alert alert-error\">";
        msg += "<h4>Sucesso!</h4>";
        msg += "Ocorreu um erro e não foi possível gerar um número.";
        msg += "</div>";
    }
    $("#numeros").empty();
    return listarNumeros();
    sysMsg(msg);
}

function listarNumeros() {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false, async:false});
    return $.getJSON("/intracake/Numeros/listar.json").done(function(data) {
        ip = data.cliente;
        numero = data.lista[0].num; //Pega o 1 resultado do array, último num gerado.
        $.each(data.lista, function(index, array) {
            inserirLinha(array);
        });
    });
}

function adicionarNumero() {
    $.post("/intracake/Numeros/adicionar.json").done(function(data) {
        atualizaTabela(data).done(function(){
            copiaArea(numero);
        });
    });
}
```

---

> **Nota: a solução abaixo foi proposta quando um dos requisitos não estava claro para mim**

Me parece que para resolver o problema seria suficiente retirar a chamada de `copiaArea` da função `adicionarNumero`, e passar para `listarNumeros`. Com isso, você pode inclusive se livrar da variável global (sobre isso, ver *[Por que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/925/por-que-usar-variaveis-globais-nao-e-uma-boa-pratica)*). Ou seja:

```
function listarNumeros() {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false, async:false});
    $.getJSON("/intracake/Numeros/listar.json")
            .done(function(data) {
                ip = data.cliente;
                // remover a linha abaixo
                //numero = data.lista[0].num; //Pega o 1 resultado do array, último num gerado.

                // inserir a seguinte linha:
                copiaArea(data.lista[0].num);

                $.each(data.lista, function(index, array) {
                    inserirLinha(array);
                });
            });
}

function adicionarNumero() {
    $.post("/intracake/Numeros/adicionar.json")
            .done(function(data) {
                atualizaTabela(data);
                // remover a linha abaixo
                //copiaArea(numero);
            });
}
```

Comment: Você é ninja.
Não é a primeira vez que você me ajuda aqui no stack... vou testar e já respondo.

Comment: Se entendi bem a pergunta, não era para fazer a cópia apenas na segunda vez que a função `listarNumeros()` fosse chamada?

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Xi, aí não sei, vamos esperar o autor esclarecer isso.

Comment: @MarceloAymone Obrigado pelo elogio, mas não foi nada ninja chegar até essa resposta :) Tive de focar um tempo no seu código até entender esse fluxo...

Comment: Mas então, bfava, eu não queria que ele acionasse o objeto window.clipboardData na primeira listagem, somente após o click, pois o script lista os números gerados anteriormente, mas ele deve acionar o clipBoard somente após a chamada do `adicionaNumeros()` porque o model do clipboard abre quando inicia a cópia.

Comment: Exatamente @carlosrafaelgn, bem observado!

Comment: Dê uma olhada no meu fiddle, @MarceloAymone, e veja se era isso (as linhas marcadas com `@@@` foram as que criei): http://jsfiddle.net/USnmL/1/

Comment: Hummm Agora entendi!!
Você também é ninja @carlosrafaelgn!!

Comment: Que vergonha minha cara, chamando sua solução "like pattern" de gambiarra. hauhaeueauh Cara é professor no ITA.
Obrigado Mestre!!

Comment: Oi @MarceloAymone! Então, não sou professor lá, não. Sou formado lá :) Agora... não conheço o "like pattern"...

Comment: Desculpe, mania de inglesar gírias... porque o finite state machine, ou máquina de estado finito seria um padrão de codificação para determinados problemas, como este.

Comment: Agora entendi, @MarceloAymone. Atualizei minha resposta com uma outra solução, que acho mais "estilo assíncrono" do que usar flags de status.

Comment: Estava olhando algumas publicações que exploram as promises como vc já citou, estava procurando este tipo de solução... vou testar aqui.

Comment: @bfavaretto Funcionou perfeitamente!!! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar um contador global e uma [guard condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computer_science%29) para sincronizar a execução das suas ações assíncronas. Mais ou menos como é feito em uma [Máquina de Estados](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_estados_finitos).

No seu código, isso ficaria assim (apenas as modificações):

Trecho 1:

```
var estado = 0;

function executaFim() {
    if (estado >= 3)
        copiaArea(numero);
}
```

Trecho 2:

```
function listarNumeros() {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false, async:false});
    $.getJSON("/intracake/Numeros/listar.json")
            .done(function(data) {
                // seu código original
                estado++;
                executaFim();
            });
}
```

Trecho 3:

```
function adicionarNumero() {
    $.post("/intracake/Numeros/adicionar.json")
            .done(function(data) {
                // seu código original
                estado++;
                executaFim();
            });
}
```