# Mysql retorna apenas o primeiro registro

Tags: php, mysql

Criei está função, mas, ela retorna só o primeiro registro da tabela.

```
function pega_conteudo_pela_id($id_assunto){

    global $conexao;

    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM `{$id_assunto}`";

    $result3 = mysqli_query($conexao,$query3) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conexao) . "<hr>\nQuery: $query3");  

    while ($leiDB = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
        return utf8_encode($leiDB['conteudo']. "<br/>");
    }
}
```

Mas se coloco na página dos links, ele funciona e pega todos os registros

```
    case 'codigo-civil':

        $query3 = "SELECT * FROM `codigo-civil`";

        $result3 = mysqli_query($conexao,$query3);

        while ($leiDB = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
            echo utf8_encode($leiDB['conteudo']. "<br/>");
        }

        break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás a usar `return` dentro da função `pega_conteudo_pela_id`, mas na prática parece-me que essa função não precisa retornar nada pois no outro exemplo estás a fazer `echo` do que precisas. O `return` interrompe a função. Remove o `return` e coloca `echo`, ou se quiseres que a função retorne o conteudo dessa query podes fazer assim:

```
echo pega_conteudo_pela_id($variavel);
```

e dentro da função:

```
$results = '';
while ($leiDB = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
    $results.= utf8_encode($leiDB['conteudo']. "<br/>");
}
return $results;
```

Um nota semântica: quando chamas a função de  `pega_conteudo_pela_id` dá-me ideia que queres ir buscar dados pela ID de uma coluna da BD. Mas no teu exemplo o parâmetro `$id_assunto` da função é usado para selecionar uma coluna. Eu mudaria esses nomes para não enganar sobre a funcionalidade que cumprem.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, mudei para `echo` e funcionou, não sabia disso, o `return` volta apenas um resultado. Obrigado!!!

Comment: @AlêMoraes fiz um edit caso queiras mesmo usar o `return` da função.

Comment: obrigado, tem alguma diferença entre usar o `echo` e o `return`, além de o `return` interromper a execução no primeiro laço?

Comment: @AlêMoraes tem a ver com fluxo de dados e como queres usar o retorno da função. É prático usar o retorno da função junto da linha que chamou a função por questões de organização de código. Se chamas uma função que está noutro ficheiro e a função faz echo de HTML pode ser dificil saber o que o código está a fazer.  Mas no fundo não há efeito no código para alem do `return` interromper a função.

Answer (score 1):

O comando "return" interrompe o laço de execução no primeiro loop, por isso está retornando somente o primeiro registro que encontra.

Troque `return` por `echo` e veja a diferença

```
return utf8_encode($leiDB['conteudo']. "<br/>");
```

Troque por **echo**

```
echo utf8_encode($leiDB['conteudo']. "<br/>");
```

obs: Vou me ater a comentar sobre o código, boas práticas de programação, etc.
Mas acho válido orientá-lo de que o código está muito mal escrito. Procure sobre boas práticas de programação.

Comment: kkkkkkkk, muito mal escrito? kkkk, foi até gentil, vlw. Tem algum erro gritante para me aconselhar? mas de qualquer forma, vlw pela ajuda

Comment: rsrs.. é que não vem ao caso extender o assunto para outro tema.. acho que vc pode estudar e, quando tiver dúvida sobre o assunto, pergunte que a galera vai te ajudando..

Comment: @AlêMoraes três pontos que posso mencionar é o uso do [global](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/925/por-que-usar-vari%C3%A1veis-globais-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-uma-boa-pr%C3%A1tica), [vulnerabilidade a SQL Injection](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php) e o [uso de funções `mysql_*`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Obrigado @gmsantos, vou tentar melhorar estes pontos, apesar de estar muito curioso, para saber qual o problema destes três ponto e como resolvê-los, kkkk. Abração

Comment: @AlêMoraes nesses três links estão bem explicados quais os problemas de cada ponto. Caso tenha uma dúvida que não está contemplada nessas questões, pode abrir uma nova pergunta :)

Comment: Ok @gmsantos, irei estudá-los, muito obrigado pela ajuda, já deu pelo menos uma direção. Vlw man. Abração