# Por que costumam dizer que o uso de variáveis globais é uma má prática?

Tags: princípios-de-programação, paradigma-de-programação, variáveis-globais

Vou direto ao assunto. Em tutoriais internet a fora, sempre você acha alguém criticando alguma, considerando aquilo como uma "má prática".

Por exemplo, uma delas é a utilização da palavra-chave `global`.

Até onde pode alcançar meu humilde entendimento, linguagens como `Python` e `PHP` (se tiver mais podem citar), aceitam isso.

Por exemplo:

```
counter = 0;

 def faz_alguma_coisa():

    global counter
    counter = counter + 1


faz_alguma_coisa()
faz_alguma_coisa()

print(counter) # 2
```

Também é possível fazer isso em `PHP`.

```
$variable = 1;

function imitando_python()
{
      global $variable;

      $variable += 1;
}

imitando_python();

var_dump($variable); // 2
```

Por esse código eu consigo perceber que pode ter um problema com o escopo da variável.

Mas falar que algo é má prática simplesmente porque uma coisa ruim não é muito da minha praia.

Então, gostaria de saber:

- Por que usar `global` (variáveis globais) seria uma má prática?
- Existe algum caso onde o uso de `global` seria essencial, ou há outras práticas melhores?

Comment: Duplicada!!!!!!!
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/925/por-que-usar-vari%C3%A1veis-globais-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-uma-boa-pr%C3%A1tica

Comment: Tudo tem uma forma de ser para cada tipo de paradigma utilizado , acredito que há vantagens e desvantagens para cada tipo de linguagem. Utilizar linguagens mais fortemente tipadas por exemplo garante que não haja tantos erros.

Answer (score 2):

Como isso abrange varias linguagens vou responder com um exemplo simples em JS:

```
i = null;
function contador1(){
    for(i = 0; i < 60; i++){
        if((i%5) == 0){
            contador2();
        }
    }
}

function contador2(){
    for(i = 0; i < 60; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Note que este loop não vai funcionar devidamente, pois `i` é global e o `contador2` vai sobrescrever a mesma variável do `contador1`.

Seria melhor ter uma variável local ou encapsular para assim não ter conflitos.