# Alternativas para variáveis globais

Tags: design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, projeto-de-software

Quais seriam as melhores práticas para se evitar o uso de variáveis globais?
Como guardar o usuário logado ou um nome de arquivo que será acessado em diversos lugares por exemplo?

Comment: para evitar o uso de variáveis globais você provavelmente vai encapsular elas em uma classe, que se torna uma "dependência" de outras classes, no meu caso eu acabei indo para IoC Container e registrando as interfaces/classes em um Service Locator, você pode dar uma olhada aqui https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx

Comment: [Por que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/925/91) e [Quais problemas um estado global pode acarretar?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## O *design* deve reduzir a necessidade por dados globais

Se há necessidade de fazer uso de um nome de arquivo em vários pontos do código, então provavelmente o acesso ao conteúdo deste arquivo não está localizado, mas disperso. Se este é o caso, então a sugestão é refatorar o código para concentrar este uso disperso em um único arquivo, possivelmente em uma única classe, possivelmente em uma única rotina ou método.

Observe que se não é apenas o nome do arquivo, mas vários outros dados cujo acesso ocorre em vários pontos do código, então quase que seguramente o código em questão é altamente acoplado. Em consequência, se possível, se viável, o código deve passar por um esforço de refatoração e reduzir este "débito técnico".

Por último, subjacente aos parágrafos anteriores está a premissa de que tais "dados globais introduz uma complexidade não essencial", ou seja, foi criada, provavelmente sem intenção de complicar, mas é uma complexidade acidental, não é decorrente do problema em questão, mas da opção de *design* do código.