# Qual a diferença entre variáveis globais e superglobais?

Tags: php, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis

Eu li a algum tempo que o PHP possui a grande maioria de suas variáveis declaradas com escopo local.

Mas encontrei outros dois *conceitos* variáveis [globais](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.globals.php) e [super globais](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.superglobals.php) e não compreendi muito bem a diferença entre ambas.

- Qual a diferença entre variáveis globais e super globais?
- Quando se deve(ria) usar cada tipo específico?

Comment: Se puderem comentar porque a pergunta esta ruim e como posso melhorá-la seria interessante também.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Variáveis Super Globais

As variáveis super globais são variáveis nativas do PHP e recebem esse nome pois estarão presentes em qualquer escopo do programa. Elas foram introduzidas no PHP 4.1.0 e são:

- [$GLOBALS](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.globals.php): Referencia todas variáveis disponíveis no escopo global;
- [$_SERVER](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php): Informação do servidor e ambiente de execução;
- [$_GET](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php): Variáveis da requisição HTTP GET;
- [$_POST](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php): Variáveis da requisição HTTP POST;
- [$_FILES](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.files.php): Arquivos enviados via HTTP POST;
- [$_COOKIE](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.cookies.php): Cookies definidos na requisição HTTP;
- [$_SESSION](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php): Variáveis de sessão;
- [$_REQUEST](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.request.php): Variáveis de requisição HTTP;
- [$_ENV](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.environment.php): Variáveis de ambiente;

O comportamento das variáveis super globais podem ser afetadas com configurações como [`variables_order`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) e [`register_globals`](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals). Sendo as variáveis super globais nativas, não é permitido ao desenvolvedor definí-las. Ou seja, não existirá nenhuma outra super global senão as supracitadas, salvo se em versões futuras do PHP outra for definida.

#### Variáveis variáveis

Um comportamento das variáveis super globais que difere de outras variáveis é que elas não sofrem com o comportamento das variáveis variáveis em escopos locais, seja dentro de funções ou métodos. Isto é, considerando o código abaixo:

```
function get_id() {

    $var = "_GET";

    return ${$var}["id"];
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/DkTTXZ).

Será lançado o erro:

> Undefined variable: _GET

Mesmo se você, por acaso, desejar incluir a variável no escopo (o que não faz sentido):

```
function get_id() {

    global $_GET;

    $var = "_GET";

    return ${$var}["id"];
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/AAUDAF).

## Variáveis Globais

Por sua vez, as variáveis globais são variáveis comuns definidas no escopo global da aplicação, porém, diferente de algumas outras linguagens de programação, as variáveis globais não estão definidas em todos os escopos por padrão, sendo necessário informar quando uma variável é externa ao escopo local. Isso pode ser feito utilizando `global`. Por exemplo, considere o código abaixo:

```
$x = 1;

echo $x, PHP_EOL;

function foo() {
    $x = 2;

    echo $x, PHP_EOL;
}

foo();

echo $x, PHP_EOL;
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/AJd3qD).

Considerando o comportamento natural de variáveis globais, a saída esperada seria `1, 2, 2`, pois o valor de `$x` seria modificado dentro da função, porém no PHP a saída é `1, 2, 1`, pois o que acontece é que a variável `$x` é local, não afetando o valor da variável global. Porém, se indicar `$x` como global:

```
$x = 1;

echo $x, PHP_EOL;

function foo() {
    global $x;

    $x = 2;

    echo $x, PHP_EOL;
}

foo();

echo $x, PHP_EOL;
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ckDPLc)

A saída, sim, será `1, 2, 2`, pois agora a variável global foi afetada pela função.

#### Funções anônimas

O mesmo acontece com funções anônimas, quando necessário utilizar variáveis externas. Por exemplo, para multiplicar uma lista de valores por um fator:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$factor = 2;

function multiplica($array) {

    $factor = 5;

    $array = array_map(function ($value) {
        global $factor;
        return $value * $factor;
    }, $array);

    return $array;

}

print_r(multiplica($array));
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/j4QePW).

O resultado será a multiplicação da lista pelo fator 2, pois ao utilizar `global $factor` a variável `$factor` é importada do escopo global, não do escopo superior ao atual. Se não existir a variável global, um resultado inesperado ou erro será produzido.

## Variáveis variáveis

E contrariando o comportamento das super globais, as variáveis globais funcionam com as variáveis variáveis.

```
$foo = "SOpt";

function foo () {

    global $foo;

    $var = "foo";

    echo $$var, PHP_EOL;
}

foo();
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/JncC2t).

Desde que, obviamente, a variável global seja incluída no escopo da função utilizando a diretiva `global`. Caso contrário, a variável não estará definida, gerando o erro:

```
$foo = "SOpt";

function foo () {
    $var = "foo";

    echo $$var, PHP_EOL;
}

foo();
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ztIkmW).

Todas as variáveis globais e super globais se encontrarão no *array* associativo definido em `$GLOBALS`. Sendo esta uma variável super global, pode ser utilizada em qualquer escopo, mas vale lembrar que variáveis locais a este escopo não estarão incluídas no *array*, apenas as globais.

## Quando se deve(ria) usar cada tipo específico?

As variáveis super globais você utilizará quando necessitar de algum valor definido pelo PHP nas variáveis citadas no início da resposta. Isto é, se você precisa acessar o valor de uma sessão, `$_SESSION`, ou recuperar informações provenientes do servidor web, `$_SERVER`. Coo dito anteriormente, não há como o desenvolvedor definir uma nova variável super global, apenas utilizá-las quando necessário. Por sua vez, as variáveis globais deverão ser utilizadas quando isso fizer sentido para a sua aplicação. Isto é, quando uma função fizer uso de algum valor externo e que não seja semântico passá-lo por parâmetro. Um exemplo prático poderia ser um arquivo de log da aplicação; supondo que exista a função `add`, que soma dois valores e gere o respectivo log:

```
function add($x, $y, $handle_log) {
    $result = $x + $y;

    fwrite($handle_log, "O resultado da soma {$x}+{$y} foi {$result}");

    return $result;
}
```

O uso da função seria algo assim:

```
$handle_log = fopen("log.txt", "w");

$result = add(1, 2, $handle_log);

echo $result;
```

Perceba que não faz muito sentido você ter que passar `$handle_log` como parâmetro de uma função sendo que o objetivo dela é apenas somar dois valores. Uma alternativa seria:

```
$handle_log = fopen("log.txt", "w");

function add($x, $y, ) {
    global $handle_log;

    $result = $x + $y;

    fwrite($handle_log, "O resultado da soma {$x}+{$y} foi {$result}");

    return $result;
}

$result = add(1, 2);

echo $result;
```

Fazendo com que a chamada da função faça sentido conforme o objetivo da mesma. Existem muitas outras alternativas além dessa, possivelmente muito mais elegantes, mas é um exemplo. Em resumo, você pode/deve utilizar uma variável global quando isso fizer sentido para a sua solução.

---

Leituras interessantes:

[Por que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/925/5878)

Comment: Bela explicação +1

Answer (score 10):

A diferença é que as super globais não há a necessidade de informar `global $variavel`, você simplesmente acessa. Elas estão disponíveis em todos os escopos, são elas:

1. $GLOBALS
2. $_SERVER
3. $_GET
4. $_POST
5. $_FILES
6. $_COOKIE
7. $_SESSION
8. $_REQUEST
9. $_ENV

Já as variáveis globais (não as super), para ter acesso a ela em diferentes escopos, você precisa informar `global $variavel` antes de utilizá-la (em cada escopo). Só após este comando que ela estará disponível para ti no código.