# Usando obj de conexao em outra classe

Tags: php

```
<?php
ob_start();
# Dados de ConexÃ£o com o Banco de dados Principal
$con_bd[banco]  =   "teste";
$con_bd[login]  =   "teste";
$con_bd[senha]  =   "teste";
$con_bd[server] =   "teste";
$error          =   "";

$con    =   mysql_connect($con_bd[server],$con_bd[login],$con_bd[senha]);

if (!$con) {
    $error = "Falha ao estabelecer uma conexao com o banco de dados!";
} else {
    mysql_select_db($con_bd[banco],$con); 
}


//Realiza a ConexÃ£o com o Banco de Dados via PDO   
if(is_null($pdo)){
    $dsn = "mysql:host=".$con_bd[server].";dbname=".$con_bd[banco];
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $con_bd[login], $con_bd[senha]);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $error = "Falha ao estabelecer uma conexao com o banco de dados!";
    }
}

ob_end_clean();

echo $error;
?>
```

Outro arquivo:

```
namespace classes\relatorio\classes;

$nivel = str_repeat("../",3);

include ($nivel.'files/conecta.php');
include ($nivel.'files/funcoes.php');


class Campos

    public function sqlResult($sql){

                    $sql = $pdo->query($sql);
                            if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
                    }
```

Mesmo usando `Use` ou `Include` não consigo usar o objeto `$con` e nem `$pdo` na minha classe, e não tenho permissão de alterar o arquivo de conexão. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Você precisa importar o objeto no escopo global para o escopo local do método utilizando [`global`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Velho vc é um gênio!

Answer (score 0):

Nem vou entrar em muitos detalhes sobre a real necessidade de se utilizar classe ou de se fazer injeção de dependência na classe definida para construir devidamente o escopo que será utilizado, pois provavelmente isso nem faria muito sentido apenas vendo um pequeno trecho de código da sua aplicação. De qualquer forma, se deseja utilizar classes da melhor forma possível, recomendo aprofundar mais seus estudos em orientação a objetos.

Mas, respondendo a pergunta, o problema no seu código é o escopo. Você está, dentro do método da classe, tentando acessar um objeto que pertence ao escopo global. O PHP, por padrão, não importa as variáveis globais para os escopos locais, então precisará fazer isso manualmente através da diretiva `global`:

```
class Campos
    public function sqlResult($sql){

        global $pdo;

        ...
    }
}
```

Eu respondi algo referente às variáveis globais do PHP nesta pergunta:

[Qual a diferença entre variáveis globais e superglobais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227200/5878)