# O que é e como usar array_walk?

Tags: php

estou aprendendo sobre mvc por meio de uma serie de vídeo-aulas no youtube, ate ai tudo bem, mais o cara chegou em um ponto que acabou utilizando array_walk().

Não consegui entender o seu funcionamento.

O código completo é este + abaixo e o vídeo esta no link logo depois (4 min de vídeo só). Mais ja adiantando, ele esta obtendo a url que o usuário esta tentando acessar e depois verificando nas rotas já definidas.

Eu travei pq não consegui entender esta declaração:

```
array_walk($this->routes, function($route) use($url) {
    ...
}
```

Pesquisei no manual do PHP e pelo que entendi a função anonima recebe um parâmetro e uma chave: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk.php (exemplo #1).

No tutorial que estou assistindo a função só esta recebendo o parâmetro ou seria a chave (não entendi bem). O ***use*** serve para acessar variáveis fora do escopo, mais ela nao esta vindo de fora do escopo, esta sendo passada por parâmetro em ***public function run($url)***, isso ja seria fora de escopo?

```
array_walk(array, function(parametro/chave?) use(fora escopo?) {
    ...
}
```

Seu alguém souber usar o array_walk e poder me explicar seu uso tbm, me ajudaria muito.

***Código Completo:***

```
namespace app;

class Init
{
    private $routes;

    //Construtor
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->initRoutes();
        $this->run($this->getUrl());
    }

    //Criando Rotas
    public function initRoutes()
    {
        $ar['home'] = array('route'=>'/', 'controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'index');
        $ar['empresa'] = array('route'=>'/empresa', 'controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'empresa');
        $this->setRoutes($ar);
    }

    //Rotas
    public function run($url)
    {
        array_walk($this->routes, function($route) use($url) {
            if($url == $route['route']) {
                echo "encontrou!!!";
            }
        });
    }

    //Setando rotas na variavel $routes
    public function setRoutes(array $routes)
    {
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    //Pegando url q usuario esta tentando acessar
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH);
    }
}
```

Link Vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7r1fHI9U4A&index=11&list=PLtxCFY2ITssBl_nihh4HC5-ZlnIPEpVQD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `array_walk` serve para aplicar uma determinada função em todos os valores de um *array*. Fica mais fácil de entender se, inicialmente, não considerarmos uma função anônima.

Então, consideremos uma função que exibe o dobro de um valor numérico:

```
function double($x) {
    echo 2*$x, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Se quiséssemos exibir o dobro de todos os valores de um *array*, poderíamos fazer:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

foreach ($array as $x) {
    double($x);
}
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/AxIdzo).

Ou utilizar a função `array_walk`, que, para fins práticos, será equivalente ao `foreach`:

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

array_walk($array, "double");
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/bqVx1b).

A diferença é basicamente que a função `array_walk` não considera o ponteiro interno do *array*, sendo assim garantido que este seja percorrido por completo em todas as chamadas, enquanto o laço `foreach` só percorre o *array* da posição do ponteiro atual até o final do *array* (ou um *break*).

A sintaxe da função é:

```
bool array_walk ( array &$arrary , string $funcname [, mixed $userdata ] )
```

- `$array` é o *array* que desejamos percorrer e aplicar a função;
- `$funcname` é o nome da função que será executada (ou uma função anônima);
- `$userdata` são parâmetros adicionais que serão passados à `$funcname`;

A função definida por `$funcname` recebe normalmente dois parâmetros: o valor presente no *array* e o respectivo índice. Ou seja, no exemplo desta resposta, a função possui apenas um parâmetro referente ao valor no *array*. O índice é ignorado. O mesmo ocorre no exemplo citado na pergunta. Porém, nem sempre esses dois parâmetros, valor e índice, são suficientes para a lógica da função, então mais parâmetros podem ser definidos e estarão relacionados com os valores em `$userdata`.

Por exemplo, digamos que a função `double` receba um terceiro parâmetro que é um multiplicador para definir o sinal, podendo ser 1 ou -1. Assim:

```
function double($value, $key, $signal) {
    echo 2*$signal*$value, PHP_EOL;
}

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array_walk($array, "double", -1);
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/MIhkKd).

Neste caso, `$signal` receberá o valor -1.

O mesmo vale para funções anônimas, como exemplificado na pergunta. O comportamento é exatamente o mesmo. Quanto a dúvida sobre o `use`, sim, o `use` serve para você importar uma variável externa para o escopo da função anônima. Mesmo que a variável seja definida como parâmetro no método onde a `array_walk` está sendo chamada, ainda assim não estará naturalmente no escopo da função anônima e por isso precisa importá-la. Vale lembrar que no PHP as variáveis globais não são importadas para escopos locais automaticamente - apenas as variáveis superglobais tem esse comportamento.

[Qual a diferença entre variáveis globais e superglobais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227200/5878)

Comment: Parabéns, agora entendi. Muito obrigado mesmo. Só ficou uma duvida referente a esta msg "**A diferença é basicamente que a função array_walk não considera o ponteiro interno do array, sendo assim garantido que este seja percorrido por completo em todas as chamadas, enquanto o laço foreach só percorre o array da posição do ponteiro atual até o final do array (ou um break)**" Não entendi a diferença, pq basicamente ele vai percorrer 0...final no array_walk e no foreach.

Comment: Nos dois primeiros exemplos, execute `next($array)` antes do `foreach` e da `array_walk` e veja a diferença. O `next` irá mover o ponteiro interno do array em uma posição, então o `foreach` não vai mais percorrer o array todo, mas a função `array_walk` sim.

Comment: Nossa, top rs
Obrigado amigo :D

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, estou estudando mvc+php com o mesmo curso dessa pergunta, e no meu caso embora o meu código seja extamente igual ao da pergunta, o meu código não executa o "echo" dentro do if. Devo criar uma nova pergunta ou pode ser respondida aqui essa dúvida ?

Comment: @GabrielSilva se o código é o mesmo, o echo não é executado porque a condição não é satisfeita.

Comment: A condição tem que ser satisfeita, porque eu conheco a condição e eu escrevi uma rota que existe e no entanto o if não a encontrou.

Comment: @GabrielSilva então faça uma nova pergunta e elabore um [mcve] demonstrando o comportamento citado.

Comment: Há quem possa interessar segue o link referente a minha dúvida.https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/420321/rota-n%c3%a3o-encontrada-php