# Variável global php vs variável não global

Tags: php

Qual a diferença entre uma Variável global e uma variável não global no PHP?
Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento desde já.

Comment: Veja se este tópico te esclarece algo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227200/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-vari%C3%A1veis-globais-e-superglobais

Comment: Obrigado. Sim esclarece.