# Escopo de variável PHP

Tags: php, variáveis, closures, scope

Então, estou batendo a cabeça há algum tempinho já com uma questão básica de escopo, mas não consegui entender o motivo.

Na função abaixo, estou tentando acessar uma posição do objeto que está rodando no momento do Foreach, entretanto ele está dando a variável $vInfo como Undefined.

Se eu der um var_dump nela antes desse array_filter, ele vai normal, somente ali dentro não funciona. Qual seria o real problema e como posso fazer para conseguir acessar o objeto dentro do array_filter?

```
 foreach ($vehiclesInfo as $vInfo) {

        $splitOpenedIdleEvents = array_filter($openedEvents, function($o){ 
            return $o->vehicleid == $vInfo->v_id;
        });
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre variáveis globais e superglobais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227200/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss opa, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É porque você não usou a chave `use`. Ela é necessária pra importar a variável pra dentro do escopo da `Closure`:

```
foreach ($vehiclesInfo as $vInfo) {

    $splitOpenedIdleEvents = array_filter($openedEvents, function($o) use($vInfo) { 
        return $o->vehicleid == $vInfo->v_id;
    });
}
```

No PHP, quando você cria uma função anônima (também chamada de `Closure`), o escopo da mesma equivale a o escopo de uma função comum. Assim como na função comum, as variáveis "de fora" não vão "para dentro" da sua função.

No caso da função anônima, pode ser resolvido através de palavra chave `use`.

Se precisar passar mais de uma variável, pode usar a `,` para separá-las, como se fossem parÂmetros:

```
$callback = function ($x) use($a, $b, $c) {

};
```

Se precisar que alterações feitas dentro da função anônima afete sua variável exteriormente, você precisa usar o operador `&` antes da mesma:

Assim:

```
    $b = 1;

    $callback = function ($x) use(&$b) {
         $b = 2;
    }

    var_dump($b);
```

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo. Agradeço a explicação geral sobre o assunto também!