# Como passar um array como parâmetro para função?

Tags: javascript

Como faço para passar um array como parâmetro para uma função? Desta forma que fiz não esta dando certo.

```
var arr = [7,4,2,12,10,9,17,20];

function soma(num1,num2) {
    resul = num1 + num2;
    return resul;
}
document.write(soma(arr[]));
```

Comment: Nos conte qual é seu objetivo. Você está somando os dois argumentos, mas passando um array. Não ficou claro pra mim.

Comment: document.write(soma(arr[0],arr[1])); é uma possibilidade ...

Comment: É que estou iniciando com javascript e tive duvida de como fazer isso, mas descobri que tenho que passar as posições do array para poder dar certo, Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Ah mais uma coisa na variável "resul" abaixo é melhor colocar o "var" antes assim "var resul = num1 + num2;", porque deu certo sem colocar o "var"                                                                                                      function soma(num1,num2) {
            resul = num1 + num2;
            return resul;
        }

Comment: Mas tome cuidado com o tamanho da array. Veja que você possui um array com 8 valores e deseja passar como parâmetro para uma função de dois argumentos.

Comment: Sim, é melhor colocar o `var` antes, sempre. Ver https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2517 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/927

Comment: Antonio, estava só com telemóvel quando respondi primeiro, mas agora melhorei a resposta e expliquei. Era isso que procuravas?

Answer (score 8):

Para passar uma array e "distribuir" os seus elementos pelos argumentos de uma função podes fazer de maneiras diferentes.

Podes fazer "à mão", como tens na pergunta e que se deve evitar pois não é flexível. Ou podes usar `.apply()` ou da maneira moderna ES6.

**Usando `.appy()`** podes passar a array como segundo argumento do método:

```
var res = soma.apply(null, arr):
```

**Usando ES6** (*"spread arguments syntax"*)  é ainda mais simples e usas somente `...` antes da array:

```
var res = soma(...arr):
```

Ambos os métodos fazem o que queres. Depois dentro da função, se não tiveres um numero fixo de argumentos podes usar a palavra reservada `arguments` que dentro da função te dá acesso a todos os argumentos. Não é uma array, mas quase, podes converter em array com `[...arguments]`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
function somar() {
  return [...arguments].reduce((sum, nr) => sum + nr, 0);
}

var arr = [1, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6];
console.log(somar(...arr)); // dá 26!
```

À maneira antiga seria assim:

```js
function somar() {
  var soma = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    soma += arguments[i];
  }
  return soma;
}

var arr = [1, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6];
console.log(somar.apply(null, arr)); // dá 26!
```