# Diferença e boas práticas, váriavel global ou de Contexto React Native

Tags: react, react-native, redux, react-navigation, contexto

Sou novo em React Native e gostaria de entender de uma forma objetiva:

Qual a diferença entre usar `global.variavel = foo;` ou criar uma api de contexto?

*'recentemente o React implementou Context Api em sua biblioteca subistituindo o Redux'*

Em uma situação como: **Passar dados** obtidos de uma página (component) **E armazenar** para ser utilizado em outro escopo em outra página (component).

qual devo utilizar? 
porque? 
são as mesmas coisas?

Não encontrei muito artigo relacionado explicando de forma "Simples e objetiva" e tenho essa duvida que pra mim no momento é muito importante para um projeto!

Answer (score 1):

São coisas bem diferentes

**Variável Global**

Você fazer `global.variavel` indica que você está declarando uma variável global que por si só implica em diversos problemas. Veja [Por que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/925/por-que-usar-vari%C3%A1veis-globais-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-uma-boa-pr%C3%A1tica).

Variável global pode te trazer diversas dores de cabeça futuramente pois qualquer função externa teria acesso a mesma.

**Context API**

A **ContextApi** nem de longe substitui o **redux**, o redux é muito mais do que só compartilhar estados. Entra performace e outras melhorias de efeitos colaterais.

Resumindo bem, contextApi você pode passar dados de um componente pai para um que seja filho dele, não precisando passar pela árvore inteira.

Normalmente você tem que passar de pai para filho seguindo a árvore. Com o Context você pode passar direto para o que precisa. Veja um exemplo prático retirado da documentação do React

```js
    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <Toolbar theme="dark" />;
      }
    }

    function Toolbar(props) {
      return (
        <div>
          <ThemedButton theme={props.theme} />
        </div>
      );
    }

    class ThemedButton extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <Button theme={this.props.theme} />;
      }
    }
```

Aqui eu preciso passar a props `theme` para o componente `ToolBar` para ele passar para o componente filho `ThemedButton`. Você não precisava do `ToolBar` para intermediar. Porém tem que passar para ele mesmo assim.

Com o **Context** você pode passar direto para o que precisa. Veja um exemplo

```js
    const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');

    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
            <Toolbar />
          </ThemeContext.Provider>
        );
      }
    }

    function Toolbar(props) {
      return (
        <div>
          <ThemedButton />
        </div>
      );
    }

    class ThemedButton extends React.Component {
      static contextType = ThemeContext;
      render() {
        return <Button theme={this.context} />;
      }
    }
```

Nesse exemplo repare que o componente `Toolbar` não passa nenhuma props para baixo (componente filho). O filho (ThemedButton), já tem acesso direto a ela.

A diferença entre variável global e context é notória, mas resumindo, o context só pode ser passado para componentes abaixo. Qualquer componente externo a árvore não pode acessar esse valor. Diferente de uma variável global, que qualquer canto pode acessa-la.

**Respondendo as perguntas**

Para compartilhamento de estado utilize a **ContextAPI**, evite ao máximo utilizar variáveis globais.

**Por que?**

A resposta está no link que coloquei de variáveis globais. Mas básicamente, você evita dor de cabeça, as vezes você pode declarar um mesmo nome e modificar achando que aquela variavel está em um escopo, mas na realidade está alterando a funcionalidade inteira da aplicação.