# Gravar dados no Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react

Meu código está assim:

```
import React from 'react';
import './addAssalariado.css'
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

export default function addAssalariado(){
    function add(){
        var name = document.getElementsByName("nome");
        var endereço = document.getElementsByName("endereço");
        var salario = document.getElementsByName("salario");

        firebase.datebase().ref('myemployees/employees/'+1).set({
            name: name,
            address: endereço,
            salay: salario
        });
    }
    return(
        <form id="comments_form" action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dados do Empregado Assalariado</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <input name="nome" id="nome" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="endereço">Endereço:</label>
            <input name="endereço" id="endereço" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="salario">Salário:</label>
            <input name="salario" id="salario" type="text" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
        <p><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" onClick={add}/></p>
    </form>
    );
}
```

Quando aperto o botão de envio aparece a mensagem na tela:

> ```
> Cannot POST /addAssalariado
> ```

Minha árvore no firebase está assim:

```
payroll-ba15c    
      myemployees     
         employees: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há algumas observações a se fazer...

**Não use var**

var faz a variavel ficar em um contexto global, prefira no caso utilizar const ou let, veja mais em [Por que usar variáveis globais não é uma boa prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/925/por-que-usar-vari%C3%A1veis-globais-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-uma-boa-pr%C3%A1tica)

**Você precisa cancelar o evento default do formulário**

O HTML vai forçar um POST pois está dentro de um form e o botão é do tipo `input` sendo assim, ele tem um evento default que executará, por isso está dizendo que fez uma requisição `POST`. Você precisa cancelar o evento default para utilizar o seu evento criado no `JS`. Para isso dentro da função de envio, pegue o evento e cancele

Segue o exemplo comentado.

```
import React from 'react';
import './addAssalariado.css'
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

export default function addAssalariado(){

    function add(e){
        e.preventDefault() //Cancelando o evento default
        const name = document.getElementsByName("nome"); //Mudando para const
        const endereço = document.getElementsByName("endereço");
        const salario = document.getElementsByName("salario");
        //O que seria esse +1? Utilize o push para criar um id novo sempre
        firebase.datebase().ref('myemployees').child('employees').push().set({
            name: name,
            address: endereço,
            salay: salario
        });
    }
    return(
        <form id="comments_form" action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dados do Empregado Assalariado</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <input name="nome" id="nome" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="endereço">Endereço:</label>
            <input name="endereço" id="endereço" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="salario">Salário:</label>
            <input name="salario" id="salario" type="text" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
        <p><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" onClick={add}/></p>
    </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: Oi, agora está aparecendo o seguinte erro

TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.datebase is not a function

apontando para a linha:

firebase.datebase().ref('myemployees/employees').push().set({

Comment: @Kamilla, editado, tente assim

Comment: Obrigada gente pelas dicas, mas eu optei por utilizar o Cloud Firestore e conseguiu.
Obrigada mesmo.